# termstrc in version of R 3.5.2

Tags: r, windows

I'm writing my master thesis degree and I have to estimate the term structure of some European banks interest rate, and I have to estimate them by the Svensson model. My version of R si 3.5.1 and it doesn't recognize the "termstc" package and I don't know how can I solve the problem. Can someone tell me how I can fix it?  I would be very grateful if someone can. I should deliver my thesis within a month.

Comment: Perhaps you mean "termstrc"? It was removed from CRAN, see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/termstrc/index.html

Comment: Thank you @Ista , yes, I meant what. I know it was removed from CRAN but I want to know if there is another way to implement/built and use it. Or if there is another similar function to "termstrc" that I couldn't find it yet. I need it for my studio. The link you posted me could help me? It is possible to use the archive items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install archived packages using `remotes::install_url`. For example,

```
remotes::install_url("https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Archive/termstrc/termstrc_1.3.7.tar.gz")
```

Of course there is a reason the package was archived, and it hasn't been updated in 5 years, so you probably *should* not. But you can, if you want.

Comment: If I run 'remotes::install_url("https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Archive/termstrc/termstrc_1.3.7.tar.gz")' it give me this error  "Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘remotes’", so I tried ' install.packages("termstrc", repos="https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/termstrc/termstrc_1.3.7.tar.gz")' but it again give me an error.

Comment: Ther error si
 'Installing package into ‘C:/Users/irma shuli/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
unable to access index for repository https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/termstrc/termstrc_1.3.7.tar.gz/src/contrib:
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘termstrc’ is not available (for R version 3.5.2)
Warning in install.packages :
unable to access index for repository . cannot open URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/termstrc/termstrc_1.3.7.tar.gz/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/PACKAGES'

Comment: No, you can not use `install.packages` because the package has been removed from CRAN and only exists in the archive. Install the `remotes` package and use it to install `termstrc`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate your commitment to responding to me. But a last thing: I run  "install.packages(" termstrc", dependencies=TRUE)" and it give me an error that Remote package is not available for the  R version 3.5.2. It's my first time I use RStudio, I'm self-taught because my thesis supervisor has not answered me for months and I only have another month to finish my thesis. Can it help if I install an older versione of RStudio? Thank you for your answers

Comment: First do `install.packages("remotes")`, then `remotes::install_url("https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Archive/termstrc/termstrc_1.3.7.tar.gz")`

Comment: that's what I did but it doesn't work anyway, install.packages("remotes") works but when I run the second command it give me this error message:

tar.exe: Archive entry has empty or unreadable filename ... skipping.
tar.exe: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
Error: Does not appear to be an R package (no DESCRIPTION)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: running command 'tar.exe -zxf "C:\Users\IRMASH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpmgl1u8\file30c45eff6ef7.tar.gz" -C "C:/Users/IRMASH~1/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpmgl1u8/remotes30c471cc3f84"' had status 1

Comment: 2: In utils::untar(tarfile, ...) :
  ‘tar.exe -zxf "C:\Users\IRMASH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpmgl1u8\file30c45eff6ef7.tar.gz" -C "C:/Users/IRMASH~1/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpmgl1u8/remotes30c471cc3f84"’ returned error code 1

3: running command 'tar.exe -ztf "C:\Users\IRMASH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpmgl1u8\file30c45eff6ef7.tar.gz"' had status 1 .

Comment: That error message is a separate issue from the question asked and answered here. Did you try googling the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Package 'termstrc' was removed from the CRAN repository. You can download it from the [archive](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/termstrc/) and install the package manually in Rstudio or using the following command:

```
install.packages("C:/Users/eco/termstrc.zip")
```

Besides, there will be some errors when you load this packages (eg. Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘termstrc’ in loadNamespace).  Just install the related packages as the following command:

```
install.packages("urca")
install.packages("sandwich")
install.packages("lmtest")
install.packages("rgl")
```